# Remove applications in virtual machine (via VMWare Fusion) from Open With options on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, virtualization, vmware

I am running Windows 7 in a virtual machine. Now all of its applications are available via the Open With (or even as the default for some) on the Mac. I don't want them there. I've remapped the ones where it was the default, but it is still listed on the Open With menu. How can I remove all of them?

I have shared folders turned off.

I've seen this with Parallels too, and I thought I saw a option to turn it off, but I cannot find it.

Comment: This should be asked on superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**VMWare 3.1.2**

- Go to Virtual Machine > Settings > Applications > Default Applications
- Uncheck the box: "Open your Mac files and web links using XX applications

**Parallels 6.0**

- Go to Virtual Machine > Configure > Applications
- Uncheck the box: "Share windows applications with Mac"

Comment: Any idea how to make this the default? Every new Linked Clone re-enables this, polluting my system.

Answer (score 5):

To complete [@nuc answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/remove-applications-in-virtual-machine-via-vmware-fusion-from-open-with-options/11088#11088), you also need to

- shutdown your virtual machine
- navigate to it in the Finder
- right-click `Show Package Content`
- delete the `Applications` folder

Comment: Where are my Virtual Machine files located?

Comment: The easiest for you would be to open VMware Fusion, right click on the virtual machine and select `Show in Finder`

Comment: My PC Gets stuck shutting down since removal of "Application" folder.
I did not like that...

Comment: This is definitely the right way, in order to find the Application folder I used spotlight. Find the rouge app you want to suppress, highlight it in the list and press ⌘+⏎ to open the folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VMWare 3.x, you can try the Steps mentioned in [this Article](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1055160#1055160) from the VMWare-Community.

Additionally, you can trash the file "com.apple.LaunchServices.plist" found in ~/Library/Prefences. The List of Applications listed in the context-menu will be rebuild the next time you try to open a file via the context menu